# Prevent text selection on double clicking a div disguised as a button

Tags: html, css, button

**Not an X/Y problem. Just curious if what I ask is possible.**

I'm trying to make a div act as a button by giving it most of the native properties that the `<button>` has but it seems like I can't replicate the behaviour of double clicking the button doesn't selects its content.

Most of the "fixes" I've found just disables selection all together but that is not a fix because regular `<button>` can still be selected if pressing CTRL+A in a web document.

I've tried to use the `apperance: button` but to no avail. Is the browser doing something finicky for buttons that can't be seen in the dev tool?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: X/Y problem? WHY do you want to make a div behave like a button against all accessibility recommendations?

Comment: Not a X/Y problem. I simply want to know if the above is possible in HTML/CSS or if the browser is doing something to the button element that can't be replicated in user land.

Comment: So you WANT the text of the button to be selected. That is very unclear

Comment: I want nothing. I'm not here to solve an actually real life problem. I'm here to discuss if what I want to do is possible but it sounds like it isn't without using ugly hacks and non-native functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) div.style.userSelect = 'unset';
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  div.style.userSelect = 'none';
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

div,
button {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  border: none;
  user-select: none;
}

div:active,
button:active {
  background-color: red;
}

span {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>I'm a little button</div>
<button>I'm a realy button</button>
<span>Press CTRL + A</span>
```

Comment: This disables text selection all together. If you test with a regular `<button>` you can't select the text when double/triple-clicking it, but if you select everything on the page you can see the text in the button also becomes selected. This doesn't work with this piece of code.

Comment: @hornta Do you want your `div` to not be selected by mouse, but selected by `Ctrl+A`?

Comment: @hornta I fix it, but the statement that the button can be selected is not true. I showed this.

Comment: I'm not looking for any specific, I just want to know if it's possible to emulate a button exactly like the browser do only using HTML/CSS but I guess it's impossible.

regular buttons content can be selected but you've disabled text-selection in your CSS.

Comment: @hornta Unfortunately, my English is probably too weak to understand what interests you. I think it is impossible to make a full-fledged button out of the block, at least for reasons of accessibility.